# Get the user name and identity right after login success

Tags: jquery, vb.net, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.0.

After login success, I want to get the user name and identity (of the successfully logged in user).

I tried the follwing without success

```
If IsValid Then
Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()

Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(UName.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout:=False)

        Select Case result

            Case SignInStatus.Success
```

Tried this after `SignInStatus.Success`

```
 Dim usid = signinManager.GetVerifiedUserId
```

Or

```
Dim usid =User.Identity.Name
```

Or

```
Dim usid =  User.Identity.GetUserId
```

I can get the user id and name on reloading the page. But I am having trouble reloading page programmatically through

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

Or

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "reload", "reloadPage()", True)
```

What am I doing wrong? *Note: I am using jQuery Mobile on this page.*

Answer (score 0):

You just set the user information when user logs in only. You should get every time user id in your load event instead. Make sure that you write code outside **!IsPostback()** block if you don't use session or viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

Well I decided to use a little common sense instead of fighting with the code or API.(Time is also important!!)
Once the user has logged in successfully (Case SignInStatus.Success) then why to be fussy, I get this particular user by using the username he entered.

```
Dim thisUser = manager.FindByName(UName.Text)
```

Then get other information by

```
Dim thisUserId As String = thisUser.Id.ToString
Dim thisUserEmail As String = thisUser.Email
etc. etc.
```